# How can configure differnets customize view outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

i have configured same account in differents outlook, the problem it's the customize view, each user has his personal view, but when one applies view, it applies to all.

How can applies differents customize view in differents outlook and don't shared the same view?

Thanks,

PD: srry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Outlook stores its views right in mailboxes and applies view per folder. So, in case of shared mailbox you have the current view applied for all users.